# Angular 4 scheduled form autosave

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to implement form data autosave in Angular 4. It should work like this:

- User changes some data in the form -> some save request to DB is invoked.
  Let's assume some timer is started here for 2s.
- During 2s from previous save request all changes will not invoke any requests (to reduce DB load), but will trigger another save request then 2s timer will expire.
- If no timer is started at the moment then save request should be invoked immediately.

I suppose that `Observable`, `Subject` and `Scheduler` from RxJS will help me, but I am completely new to it. Could you suggest the best approach for achieving above functionality please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can just subscribe to [`valueChanges` property on `FormGroup` object](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges) chained with the [`auditTime`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-auditTime) operator:

```
this.form.valueChanges.auditTime(2000).subscribe(formData => /* save to DB */)
```

Maybe also have a look at `throttleTime` and `debounceTime` operators.

Comment: Thank you! `auditTime` operator is exactly what I needed! So simple and elegant solution.

Comment: Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46094431/how-to-implement-auto-save-a-reactive-form-in-angular-4

Answer (score 14):

For Angular 6, you may have to use pipe.

```
this.form.valueChanges.pipe(auditTime(2000)).subscribe(formData => /* save to DB */)
```